# How can I write scenario test for another domains with Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to write a scenario test which will perform remote web site? How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `browser().navigateTo('http://whereveryouwant.com')`, and then use any of the [e2e api](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing) methods to manipulate the page and make assertions.

The major caveat is that Angular's scenario runner doesn't support full page reloads, so this will limit what you can do in your tests. If you do anything on the page that results in a full page reload, the test runner will freeze up.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers don't support cross site requests. So there is no way to do what you want.

You need to make it look to the browser as if the local e2e runner and the remote site are on the same domain. And the only way to do that is with a proxy.